# How to put 2 text box over a fluid img ? one top left, the other bottom right - see screenshot

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want two text boxes overlay an image taged as img-fluid in bootstrap 4.
The first text-box will be at the top left, overlapping the image about 5%.
The other should be at the bottom right, overlapping also about 5%.

You can look here at this screenshot: [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ff8.jpg)

I trying several solutions, but no one works ....

Here is the html code:

```
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-no-padding">
        <div class="jumbotron-img">


            <div class="jumbotron-img-caption-top">
                <h1>Hotel + Restaurant <span class="fraktur">Bürgerhof Wetzlar</span></h1>
            </div>

            <img src="img/wetzlar_full.jpg" class="img-fluid">

            <div class="jumbotron-img-caption-bottom">
                <h1>der perfekte Start für Ihre Tour in und um Wetzlar!</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and here the css:

```
    .jumbotron-no-padding {
        padding: 0px!important;
    }

    .jumbotron-img {
            position: relative;
    }

    .jumbotron-img img{
            position: absolute;
            top: 5%;
    }

    .jumbotron-img-caption-top {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            right: 20rem;
            width: 100%;    
            background-color: #fff1c2;
            padding: 1.5rem;
            padding-left: 21.5rem;
    }
    .jumbotron-img-caption-bottom {
            position: absolute;
            top: 95%;
            left: 20rem;
            width: 100%;    
            background-color: #fff1c2;
            padding: 1.5rem;
    }

    .jumbotron-imgn h2 {
        line-height: 3rem;
        vertical-align: middle
    }
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. I am setting the text wrappers to `width:auto` and setting their position to left or right. I am setting either the top or bottom to 0 and then using `transform:transplateY(-50%)` to compensate for the height of the text wrappers.

I removed the absolute position from `.jumbotron-img img` because it it didn't seem to be needed and it was causing `.jumbotron-img` height to collapse so the absolute positioned positioned child elements couldn't position properly.

```css
body {
  padding-top:100px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  margin:0;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.jumbotron-no-padding {
  padding: 0px!important;
}

.jumbotron-img {
  position: relative;
}

.jumbotron-img-caption-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:auto;
  background-color: #fff1c2;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.jumbotron-img-caption-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right:0;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #fff1c2;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.jumbotron-imgn h2 {
  line-height: 3rem;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-no-padding">
  <div class="jumbotron-img">
    <div class="jumbotron-img-caption-top">
        <h1>Hotel + Restaurant <span class="fraktur">Bürgerhof Wetzlar</span></h1>
    </div>

    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000000/0011ff" class="img-fluid">

    <div class="jumbotron-img-caption-bottom">
        <h1>der perfekte Start für Ihre Tour in und um Wetzlar!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```